# Jenkins REST API to get the changes related to a particular job

Tags: rest, api, jenkins

I need to get the changes of a particular job (not the build) through rest api.

I am able to get the changes relates to a build but unable to find the rest api to get the changes of a particular job.

I have used "http://jenkis_url:port/job/job_name/changes/api/json". This does not get display any useful data that I need but throws 404 error.

I can get changes of a build using the "http://jenkis_url:port/job/job_name/build_no/api/json".

Please suggest me the REST API to get the changes of a job.